# Get Ready status using kubectl -o=jsonpath

Tags: kubernetes

I was trying to get the Ready status of pods by using -o=jsonpath.
To be more clear of what I want, I would like to get the value 1/1 of the following example using  -o=jsonpath.

```
NAME       READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
some_pod   1/1       Running   1          34d
```

I have managed to get some information such as the pod name or namespace.

```
kubectl get pods --all-namespaces -o=jsonpath='{range .items[*]}{"\n"}{.metadata.namespace}{"\t"}{.metadata.name}{"\t"}{end}'
```

And I get somthing like:

> some_namespace1    pod_name1

However, I don't know how to get the Ready status. What I would like to have is an aoutput similar to this:

> some_namespace1    pod_name1   1/1

I know I can use bash commands like cut:

```
kubectl get pods --all-namespaces| tail -1 | cut -d' ' -f8
```

However, I would like to get it by using kubectl

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get all the pods status using the following command:

```
kubectl get pods -o jsonpath={.items[*].status.phase}
```

Similar commands you can use for the name

```
kubectl get pods -o jsonpath={.items[*].metadata.name}
```

EDIT:

You need to compare the `.status.replicas` and `.status.readyReplicas` to get how many ready replicas are there.

Comment: Yes I know, as I have added in the question I can get many things by using jsonpath. However, I would like to specifically get the ready status. If I check all the json by using: `kubectl get pod -o json` I don't see anywhere the 1/1 string

Comment: No In that case you need to compare the `.status.replicas` and `.status.readyReplicas` to get that

Comment: You may need to add quotes around jsonpath: `kubectl get pods --all-namespaces -o jsonpath="{.items[*].status.phase}"`

Answer (score 1):

I think this isn't directly reported in the Kubernetes API.

If you `kubectl get pod ... -o yaml` (or `-o json`) you'll get back an object matching a `List` (not included in the API docs) where each item is a [Pod](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.14/#pod-v1-core) in the Kubernetes API, and `-o jsonpath` values follow that object structure.  In particular a [PodStatus](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.14/#podstatus-v1-core) has a list of [ContainerStatus](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.14/#containerstatus-v1-core), each of which may or may not be `ready`, but the API itself doesn't return the counts as first-class fields.

There are a couple of different JSONPath implementations.  I think Kubernetes only supports [the syntax in the Kubernetes documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/jsonpath/), which doesn't include any sort of "length" function.  (The [original JavaScript implementation](https://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/) and a ready Googlable [Java implementation](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath) both seem to, with slightly different syntax.)

The best I can come up with playing with this is to report all of the individual container "ready" statuses

```
kubectl get pods \
  -o $'jsonpath={range .items[*]}{.metadata.name}\t{.status.containerStatuses[*].ready}\n{end}'
```

(`$'...'` is bash/zsh syntax) but this still requires some post-processing to get back the original counts.

Comment: `kubectl get pods -o jsonpath="{range .items[*]}{@.metadata.name}{'\t\t'}{@.status.conditions[?(@.type=='Ready')].status}{'\n'}"`